# Unable to create an entry with an objectid and data_relation field

Tags: python, eve

I'm having some troubles when trying to insert a document with a relation to another document. The API raises an exception with no details at all.

I'm getting the following weird issue:

```
    "_error": {
        "code": 422, 
        "message": "Insertion failure: 1 document(s) contain(s) error(s)"
    }, 
    "_issues": {
        "exception": "'application'"
    },
```

I'm using Python 3.4, Eve 0.5.3 and MongoDB 3. More details below:

The schema:

```
application_schema = {
    'label': {
        'type': 'string',
        'required': True,
        'empty': False,
        'unique': True,
    },
    'owner': {
        'type': 'string',
        'empty': False,
    },
}

application = {
    'item_title': 'application',
    'schema': application_schema
}

delivery_schema = {
    'label': {
        'type': 'string',
        'required': True,
        'empty': False,
        'unique': True,
    },
    'app': {
            'type': 'objectid',
            'required': True,
            'data_relation': {
                'resource': 'application',
                'embeddable': True
            },
    },
}

delivery = {
    'item_title': 'delivery',
    'schema': delivery_schema
}

DOMAIN = {
    'applications': application,
    'deliveries': delivery
}
```

So there is a relation between a delivery and an application. Here, I'll post an application (I'm using httpie, see https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie):

```
$ http POST :5000/api/applications label="toto"
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.0 201 CREATED
Content-Length: 252
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Wed, 13 May 2015 08:35:14 GMT
Server: Eve/0.5.3 Werkzeug/0.10.4 Python/3.4.3

{
    "_created": "2015-05-13", 
    "_etag": "fc6492cb6ba36424a9e38113026c33e49a60189d", 
    "_id": "55530cc2962bf270efba95b2", 
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "applications/55530cc2962bf270efba95b2", 
            "title": "application"
        }
    }, 
    "_status": "OK", 
    "_updated": "2015-05-13"
}
```

Now, if I try to insert a delivery using the `_id` from the previously inserted object, an exception is raised:

```
$ http POST :5000/api/deliveries label="toto" app="55530cc2962bf270efba95b2"
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.0 422 UNPROCESSABLE ENTITY
Content-Length: 153
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Wed, 13 May 2015 08:39:42 GMT
Server: Eve/0.5.3 Werkzeug/0.10.4 Python/3.4.3

{
    "_error": {
        "code": 422, 
        "message": "Insertion failure: 1 document(s) contain(s) error(s)"
    }, 
    "_issues": {
        "exception": "'application'"
    }, 
    "_status": "ERR"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `data_relation` is referencing the wrong resource (endpoint.)

Judging from your POST request (as you did not post your `DOMAIN` definition), you ended up defining `applications` and `deliveries` as your resources, hence you should reference `applications` (plural) in your data relation.

Try the following update:

```
delivery_schema = {
    'label': {
        'type': 'string',
        'required': True,
        'empty': False,
        'unique': True,
    },
    'app': {
            'type': 'objectid',
            'required': True,
            'data_relation': {
                # replace 'application' with 'applications' as
                # that's the actual endpoint (resource) name.
                'resource': 'applications',
                'embeddable': True
            },
    },
}
```

Comment: Indeed, that was the issue ! Thanks for the quick answer. I've also updated my question with the domain.

Comment: Is it possible to enter an empty field into the field "app" which has data-relation?